# Should customizing a website break a contract?

Tags: clients, contract

I have a client that asked for more administrative control of his website and attempted to perform updates and changes himself. That has resulted in a bunch of errors occurring on the site, elements getting broken, and tons of my extra time researching and answering questions.

It has been really difficult for me to jump in and figure out what he's done and then fix it. He submits tickets then withdraws them, but I've already spent time on them. He asks how much it is going to cost him this month, but I can't predict how many more issues will come up with a non-expert messing around the backend of the site.

I do have a maintenance contract that states that I'll keep regular backups of the site, update plugins etc.(which I test), and keep an eye on security for a set price per month. Now I'm going far over that time and effort, but there's resistance to paying me.

I have an "at will" clause in the contract but I do not have a clause that states that any customization or administrative tasks performed by a 3rd party (or not me) means that the contract is void or that I cannot support the site or results.

Do any of you know about similar "breaking" or "3rd party customization" clauses? Have you used them?

At this point I'm loosing so much time and money on this that I am considering terminating the maintenance contract and stating that I can no longer support the site since it is not in a controlled development environment.

Thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a business matter and not about webmastering as defined in the FAQ

Comment: I would advise you to collect metrics and present the issue first before cutting the contract. That would be professional. Make the case about the scope of changes he has made and the costs outside of the contract outline. Advise him that you need to cover the time in an agreeable way or consider terminating the contract which is not preferred. Also, double check with your attorney. Often, they will not charge you anything or much at all for simple advice. Especially for advice over e-mail which allows an attorney to answer your question and still book a full day of clients. (hint hint)

Comment: @JohnConde while that is true, perhaps the scope of the FAQ can be widened a little.  This is a good question that warrants some discussion.

Comment: This site is a Q&A site. Not a discussion site. Discussions are best suited for [chat].